# Is it possible to transform a string value once it's been validated by Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schema, formik, yup

Apologies if this has been asked already, just picked up Yup today.

Is it possible to validate a field in Yup and then transform its value to an empty string before being submitted by Formik?

The current set up has `Yup.string().required('general.input.error.required')` for the form input, but on this one occasion I need to make it nullable based on if the value is `notRequired`

I've tried some of the following, but having no luck...

```
 Yup.object().shape({
    value: Yup.string()
      .required('general.input.error.required')
      .transform((value) => (value === 'notRequired' ? '' : value)),
 })
```

and

```
Yup.object().shape({
   value: Yup.string().when('value', (value) => {
     if (value === 'notRequired') {
       return Yup.string().nullable().optional();
     } else {
       return Yup.string().required('general.input.error.required');
     }
   }
})
```

I hope the above, makes sense?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the transform on the submit function